# Has anyone used Railskits SaaS kit on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, saas

I am considering purchasing the Railskits SaaS kit and deploy the app on Heroku. Has anyone deployed a Railskits SaaS based app on Heroku? What was your experience with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind that Heroku has limitations when it comes to using SSL.  It costs $100 / mo for a custom SSL domain that will validate across all browsers.  Other than that, using SaaS kit should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted like 3 years ago, but I'm currently in the process of trying to deploy the SaaS kit to Heroku and am having a pretty bad experience. I'm not the most experienced rails dev, so it could be something as simple as Heroku having to run a pg database and I'm running sqlite3 locally, but I've deployed apps to Heroku in the past without much problem and this particular one with the SaaS kit is giving me fits! Just thought I'd put in my 2 cents :)